# Putting Java code into git?

Tags: java, git, version-control, project

I'm programming in Java, and I usually prefer git when programming in Python. So I want to use it for Java too. I'm using Eclipse, but other people may use Netbeans or IntelliJ IDEA or whatever. How is this usually managed when putting Java code into version control?

I'm making a game which uses the library LWJGL, and that library needs to be added to the project file to be used. Therefore, I still need to check the project file into my project.

Comment: Version control is independent of IDEs. Some IDEs have integration components for version control.

Comment: Take the appropriate gitignore and you're pretty much set. You don't even need an in-IDE version control system.

Comment: It's nothing else than in Python (beside the folder structure is normally much deeper in Java projects due to package naming conventions).

Comment: Then I guess this question is about how this is generally handled for Java projects, and what conventions that are adhered to.

Comment: The same way you handle it for any other language

Comment: @JeroenVannevel and ConcurrentHashMap: I'm not really asking how to do it *in my IDE*, but rather how I should handle the fact that different IDE's exist, when version controlling project files.

Comment: Typically one would add the various project files for different IDE's to the .gitignore rules.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I didn't, but that's because the process of running a Python program is independent of what editing tool you use for it.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, it doesn't matter at all. Create a file called .gitignore in the root of your project file to ignore your IDE's project files or anything like that, then add your code into the git repository. For example, a good Eclipse .gitignore [can be found here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore).

That way the other collaborators won't see your project files, and if they do the same with their .gitignore for their IDE, you won't see theirs.

Comment: This solves the problem if I always use the default build settings. But what if I want to, for example, add some libraries to the compilation process?

Comment: That configuration is contained within those same project files that have now been ignored (I believe all of that is within the .launch files in Eclipse).

Comment: Exactly! That's why I want to still have them there. But it seems like everybody downloading my source code has to use the same IDE as I do to build it. How is this problem generally tackled?

Comment: You'll have to post more about your specific setup in that case, because in general it's not true that everyone has to use the same IDE in order to build the same code - it's something specific to your situation. It might be appropriate to edit your answer with more about your project as well as what kind of errors people encounter when they try to build with a different IDE.